# Unity doesn't load after login for any user

Tags: 14.04, unity

After an update of Ubuntu 14.04 a strange behavior started. After starting X11 and logging in the screen remain black, the mouse moves, all seems to be loaded. No errors on log but unity does not load any icon, any wallpaper, any side bar.

Created a test user from scratch through the terminal, and got the same result.

Deleted all the `.config` folders and many other config files.
Reinstalled `NVidia` drivers and `ubuntu-desktop` as well as the `unity` package.

What should I do?

Comment: What happens if you press Alt+F2

Comment: Nothing, to turn to terminal I have to press CTRL+Alt+F2... the X server is up and running

Comment: Does the command `sudo service lightdm restart` get unity running?

Comment: I tryed also to switch to gdm too with the same result. The log in service is up and running, once I log on unity doesn't load anything.

Comment: run the command `startx`?

Comment: Runs another X server on another display `:1` with the same result... nothing loads up